# synctex stopped working after I used external pdf viewer

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search

I am using TexMaker and synctex was working fine until I used the external pdf viewer option for a few hours. I did not worry about it but when I went back to the embedded viewer synctex was still no longer working (no forward/reverse search).

In Configure TexMaker I have: "/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex

I am using Mac OSX Mavericks and am using the same file that worked fine before. I have not found anything online that reverses this issue.

Any thoughts? Thank you!